# How do I fix my code: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, valueerror

I am writing a program that calculates sum of two input numbers.

But 'set = int(input())', this sentence causes ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

i don't know how to fix it.

I can't speak english well.
if you can't understand my word, let me know. i will rewrite the question.

Here's my code:

```
T = int(input())

for i in range(T):
    set = int(input())
    A = int(set.split()[0])
    B = int(set.split()[1])
    print(A+B)
```

Comment: You have to enter a number at the prompt.

Comment: If you set `set` to an int then you won't be able to call `split()` on it. Also you probably shouldn't be assigning to `set`. That's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: One more advice: Even if you don't speak english very well you might want to read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Variables should be written in lower case and have meaningful names.

Comment: thank you i solved the problem

Comment: @ubaidh That never happens in the code above...

Comment: @tomeikoo the string from the input lol

Comment: Be careful of value errors when casting to int() one line 1 with the string value. You likely want to do a test on the string for `if input().isDigit()`

Comment: ...and please do not use `set` as a variable name. This is a used keyword in Python

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the code that you are entering two numbers separated by a space into the set variable.
If this is the case, and you change `int(input())` to just `input()`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't split int this way i.e. you cannot pass two int in set and split don't work on int.
1)Either remove int from set

```
T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
    set = input()
    A = int(set.split()[0])
    B = int(set.split()[1])
print(A+B)
```

2)Use one liner

```
 A, B = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

As `split` operates on strings you need to convert later. You can try this

```py
T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
    x = list(map(int, input().split()))
    A = x[0]
    B = x[1]
    print(A + B)
```

This splits the input string, which is then mapped on the function `int`, i.e. a new list is created by applying `int()` to all items. You may add some error-handling, as this codes fails if only one or even no values are provided. It also fails if the input cannot be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code guess `set = int(input())` here you should enter a string like "1 2", "1 2" can not be converted to `int` so the error is reported.

```
T = int(input())

for i in range(T):
    set = input()
    A = int(set.split()[0])
    B = int(set.split()[1])
    print(A+B)
```

This should work.